# PhpMyAdmin Import Error-MySQL server has gone away/Unrecognized Keyword

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, importerror

So I've exported a MySQL database from PHPMyAdmin (which I access from within IIS Express on a Windows 8 machine) and I'm trying to import this database onto another machine, however on that machine I receive the following errors:
[image: Error]

[image: Warning1]

[image: Warning2]

Please help. I need to be able to restore this database and I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem So I should go into my sql file and change that line?

Comment: I tried changing that line in the sql file (it was set to 0), but that didn't make a difference. 

Where is it set to ON? I can't figure that out.

Comment: If the dump is really big, either change the configuration (increase the timeout limit), or import the dump via command-line (something like `mysql -u user -p password db_name < dumpfile.sql` usually does the trick)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server has gone away often means that there is a MySQL connection timeout. This can happen if you have an especially large database dump (and it sounds like you might). [You could try fiddling with your MySQL settings in `mf.cnf`](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server) but realistically you are far better off using the command line for a file that large:

> mysql -u user -p password db_name < dumpfile.sql

Comment: Changing the MySQL settings worked. 

This is what I changed, exactly: 

In php.ini 

Find:
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M

Change to:
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M

In my.ini (MySQL File)

Under mysqld add: max_allowed_packet = 500M

Answer (score 14):

Changing the MySQL settings worked. This is what I changed, exactly:

**In php.ini**

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

**In my.ini** (MySQL File - Under mysqld)

Find:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1M
```

Change to:

```
max_allowed_packet = 500M
```

Comment: These values are REALLY high and might have unintended consequences down the road on a production server. Try starting with more reasonable values and moving up until it works.  `max_execution_time = 5000` means a single PHP process won't time out for almost an hour and a half.

Comment: For me, all I had to do was change max_allowed_packet from 1M to 5M. That setting does not need to be larger than the file... my file was about 250M.

Comment: max_allowed_packet option will help me. Thank you!